# Reconnecting to device with pySerial

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

I am currently having a problem with the pySerial module in Python. My problem relates to connecting and disconnecting to a device. I can successfully connect to my device and communicate with it for as long as I want to, and disconnect from it whenever I desire. However, I am unable to reconnect to the device once the connection has been severed.

Here is the wrapper class that my program uses to interface with the serial port:

```
import serial, tkMessageBox

class Controller:
""" Wrapper class for managing the serial connection with the MS-2000. """
    def __init__(self, settings):
        self.ser = None
        self.settings = settings

    def connect(self):
        """ Connect or disconnect to MS-2000. Return connection status."""
        try:
            if self.ser == None:
                self.ser = serial.Serial(self.settings['PORT'],
                                         self.settings['BAUDRATE'])
                print "Successfully connected to port %r." % self.ser.port
                return True
            else:
                if self.ser.isOpen():
                    self.ser.close()
                    print "Disconnected."
                    return False
                else:
                    self.ser.open()
                    print "Connected."
                    return True
        except serial.SerialException, e:
            return False

    def isConnected(self):
        '''Is the computer connected with the MS-2000?'''
        try:
            return self.ser.isOpen()
        except:
            return False

    def write(self, command):
        """ Sends command to MS-2000, appending a carraige return. """
        try:
            self.ser.write(command + '\r')
        except Exception, e:
            tkMessageBox.showerror('Serial connection error',
                                   'Error sending message "%s" to MS-2000:\n%s' %
                               (command, e))

    def read(self, chars):
        """ Reads specified number of characters from the serial port. """
        return self.ser.read(chars)
```

Does anybody know the reason why this problem exists and what I could try to do to fix it?

Comment: Whats the exception / trace you get when you try to reconnect?  And are you on Windows or Linux?

Comment: What do you mean by "connection is severed"?  You mean unplugging the serial cable, or just exiting your python process?

Comment: @andrew donelick Not related to the answer for your problem, but why don't you initialize the `Serial` object in `__init__()`?

Comment: What platforms have you tried this on? Because I've encountered similar problems with serial ports not being released on Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't releasing the serial port when you are finished. Use `ser.close()` to close the port before exiting your program, otherwise the port will stay locked indefinitely. I would suggest adding a method called `disconnect()` in your class for this.

If you are on Windows, to remedy the situation during testing, start Task Manager and kill any `python.exe` or `pythonw.exe` processes that may be locking the serial port.

Comment: Thank you. After all the searching I did to close the serial port, which Sublime Text, Python, has kept the port open when I rebuilt the project, this was the best solution.